# Fetching specific row of multiple excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to gather a specific row of multiple excel files in a single sheet. As you can see in the image I am getting bin_depth of 0.5 in each row.
[image: this is the notebook result].
But when I am saving the result. It is coming like
[image: this].
This is my code for fetching second row of multiple excel files

```
import pandas as pd
import os as os
from glob import glob

aggregate = pd.DataFrame()
dir = "/Users/gulfcarbon2/Downloads/Modis/absorption file/"
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
#         print(os.path.join("/Users/gulfcarbon2/Downloads/Modis/absorption file/", file))
        data = pd.read_excel(dir+file)
        row2 = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[1]).transpose()
        aggregate = aggregate.append(row2)
        data.to_excel("/Users/gulfcarbon2/Downloads/Modis/absorption file/aggregate1.xlsx")
        print(aggregate.head(5))
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the first line being a header. So, with the following code, you're essentially picking up line 3 of excel sheet

if you need the line 2 change as follows

```
row2 = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[0]).transpose()
```

```
aggregate.to_excel("/Users/gulfcarbon2/Downloads/Modis/absorption file/aggregate1.xlsx")
```

Comment: the code is picking the exact line that I am looking for. YOu can see that in the first image but the problem is that it is not saving the way it is showing in the output

Comment: @Arnabpaul, updated the answer, you're writing back **data** instead of **aggregate**

Comment: that was a silly mistake from my side. It worked but I did not get all the data I need. Like I hade 87 individual files but I got only 75 1st row data.